# A strange geo-puzzle

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, geography

I wanted to try something new this time. Not sure if this is (too) hard or (too) easy, and I'm curious for comments...

> ## Can you locate (and name) this real world place?

All hints are within the image.

---

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Revenue Haus (Bogan Gapo)
>
>  [image]

The building contains

> Morse code for PORT MORSBY (window width/height)
>  So I put this in [Google Maps](https://goo.gl/maps/QWiS2JGNcT32) and found it quite quickly

Comment: Well done. It was too easy then ;c) Can you explain the two other hints in the image, though?

Comment: I _think_ the ants refer to the street name (Champion Parade), but not sure about the rest to be honest.

Comment: Actually, both the image on the house and the ants refer to the name of that building. And the black forms are representative for the letters of the solution.

Comment: I was hoping that there would be enough distraction to disguise the 2D morse code, but you saw right through it 8-)

Comment: @BmyGuest I've noted that the second name for it contains six distinct letters, three of which it contains twice. Likewise, there are six shapes, three of which appear twice (ignoring the orange pentagon) - but I haven't found anything significant in terms of mapping _or_ ordering.